# SendBroadcast() doesn't work in on receive of Broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I have the main activity, that execute a service. In this service, I init a BroadcastReceiver (alarm).

Then I need send briadcast from the onReceive method of alarm broadcst, but doesn't work. But if I execute sendBroadcast() of other method in alarm, work perfectly.

See de code for explain me:

**Activity** (init service and get broadcastReceiver)

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver abcd = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Intent in = getIntent();
            //finish();
            Log.d("sdasd", "onReceive: BROADCAST RECIBIDO!!!");
        }
    };
```

**Service**

```
alarm alarm = new alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{            
    alarm.setAlarm(this, tiempo);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Alarm.class**

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

     }

    public void setAlarm(Context context, int tiempo)
    {
        Log.e("TAG", "setAlarm: ");

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("xyz"));

        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), tiempo, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute

    }
```

In alarm.class, the sendBroadcast in serAlarm() is executed, but the sendBroadcast in onreceive, doesn't executed. And the toast work perfectly.

Why?

Comment: Where did you register that `BroadcastReceiver`? In the code you shared, you instantiate it, but you don't register it

Comment: which actions is your `abcd` subscribed for? Show the code where you register `abcd` receiver

Comment: I register the abc reciver in onCreate of activity  //registerReceiver(abcd, new IntentFilter("xyz")); Reciver work fine, but not into onReceive of other broadcast

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you need to regist BroadcastReceiver in Service.class.

You can regist BroadcastReceiver in 2 way;

1. AndroidManifest.xml use

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".TestReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="xyz"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Sourcecode :

   ```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("xyz");
    registerReceiver(abcd, intentFilter);

    private final BroadcastReceiver abcd = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //Intent in = getIntent();
         //finish();
         Log.d("sdasd", "onReceive: BROADCAST RECIBIDO!!!");
      }
     };
   ```

======

".TestReceiver" example: It is Java Class File

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}}
```

Comment: What I need change for TestReceiver? alarm?

Comment: If Alarm.class is BroadcastReceiver, You can change TestReceiver to Alarm